# In Symfony, how do I build a review form (I have Entity "Review") to display from an Article controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, symfony

Here's my thoughts and where I'm at. Please tell me if any of this is bad practice!

I have 3 Entities: Article, Author, Reviews:

Relationships:

- Article has One Author.
- Article has many Reviews.
- Author has many Articles.
- Review has One Author.
- Review has One Article.

I've created a controller called reviewAction where I'm going to build a review form, pass it to a review view, and embed that on my article show view.

Here's my controller so far (it isn't working)

```
public function reviewAction(Request $request, Article $article)
{

    $reviewForm = $this->createFormBuilder($article);
    $reviewForm->add('review')->add('title')
        ->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE))
        ->add('rating', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' =>'5'),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ($reviewForm->isSubmitted() && $reviewForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('article/review.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $reviewForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

First off, is it advisable to build this form here? Seems like I'm working an awful lot with the Review type here in the Articles controllers. Not sure where else I would build it though.

I'm getting this error:

> Neither the property "review" nor one of the methods "getReview()", "review()", "isReview()", "hasReview()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Article".

So I'm really stuck and would appreciate anything that anybody can provide.

EDIT

**Here's my Article Entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"}, message="Note: That article already existed.")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $author;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $reviews;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumbnail
     *
     * @param string $thumbnail
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail)
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumbnail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDate
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
    {
        $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set authorId
     *
     * @param integer $authorId
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthorId($authorId)
    {
        $this->authorId = $authorId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get authorId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAuthorId()
    {
        return $this->authorId;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $author
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Author
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Add review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function addReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     */
    public function removeReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews->removeElement($review);
    }

    /**
     * Get reviews
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

**Here's my Review entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Review
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="review")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReviewRepository")
 */
class Review
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="smallint")
     */
    private $rating;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="reviews")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="reviews")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="review", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $review;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set rating
     *
     * @param integer $rating
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setRating($rating)
    {
        $this->rating = $rating;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rating
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRating()
    {
        return $this->rating;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set authorId
     *
     * @param integer $authorId
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setAuthorId($authorId)
    {
        $this->authorId = $authorId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get authorId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAuthorId()
    {
        return $this->authorId;
    }

    /**
     * Set review
     *
     * @param string $review
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setReview($review)
    {
        $this->review = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get review
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReview()
    {
        return $this->review;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $author
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Author
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $article
     *
     * @return Review
     */
    public function setArticle(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $article = null)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Author
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }
}
```

**Here's my article/review.html.twig file**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Review Article</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('article_index') }}">Back to the list</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**Update: This code worked**

```
$reviewForm = $this->createFormBuilder($review)
    ->add('review', ReviewType::class, array("label" => FALSE))
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('fundraiser_review', array('id' =>$fundraiser->getId())))
    ->getForm();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `reviews` instead of `review`? Try reading the error message.

Comment: Hmm, @ShiraNai7 you may be on to something but now I'm very confused at how this all works. I changed it to ->add('reviews') and the error went away. I got an error about title so I changed that to titles.... no luck. Is there anybody who can explain what I'm doing wrong here? And whether this is correct or not to build the review form in the articles controller? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Oh I see why "reviews" worked... My entity does have a reviews property property. So I'm still very stuck.

Comment: I the error is coming from your Twig file. Can you please show the respective code in this file: `article/review.html.twig`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @alvinbunk. I've included it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating an Article form, and if you look in your Article Entity, you have a `reviews` array collection, so thus you need to change the code like so:

```
$reviewForm = $this->createFormBuilder($article);
$reviewForm->add('reviews')
    ->add('title')
    ->add('author', AuthorType::class, array("label" => FALSE))
    ->add('rating', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' =>'5'),
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

I think that should solve it. Not 100% certain, but please try it and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for responding. You're on the right track pointing out that we were making an article form. I get an error with the provided code ("An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined variable: reviewForm")."). It might be fixable, but I've used some other code by now. I'm updating my answer with the new code. Thanks!

Comment: Is that error message referring to the Twig file `article/review.html.twig`?

Comment: I'm not really sure (sorry, I'm really new at Symfony and debugging in it!!!). Do you know how I could tell?

Comment: You could try accessing with the dev URL. Basically append `app_dev.php` to your host URL, like: `http://localhost/app_dev.php/some_route`. You'' get more info shown in the dev (debug) environment.